# How add NLog Class Library project in other projects

Tags: c#, nlog

I have created a console project in C# and in that project I am using NLog for logging purpose. 
When I run the project, it successfully logging into to multiple targets like Console, File, EventLog and also to Sentinal.
But when I make this project as a classLibrary and try to add the reference to another project, it's not logging to any of the targets. And of course there is no error in the project.
Following is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;

namespace NLogger
{
public class logWrapper
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public void LevelLogger(string level, string msg)
    {
        if (level == "Trace")
            Trace(msg);
        else if (level == "Info")
            Info(msg);
        else if (level == "Error")
            Error(msg);
        else if (level == "Debug")
            Debug(msg);
        else if (level == "Warn")
            Warn(msg);
    }

    public void Trace(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Trace(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Info(string msg)
    {
        logger.Info(msg);
    }

    public void Error(string msg)
    {
        logger.Error(msg);
    }
    public void Debug(string msg)
    {
        logger.Debug(msg);
    }
    public void Warn(string msg)
    {
        logger.Warn(msg);
    }

    //Uncomment following when the project type is Console App. --Debugging purpose only

    //public static void Main(string[] args)
    //{
    //    logWrapper l = new logWrapper();
    //    l.LevelLogger("Info", "INFORMATION");
    //}
}
}
```

Following is Nlog.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<targets>
<target xsi:type="File" name="file" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${callsite:fileName=true}${newLine}"
        fileName="C:\Users\sharathk\Desktop\ToCompare\${shortdate}_Log.txt"/>
<target name="viewer" xsi:type="NLogViewer" address="udp://10.100.18.166:9999"/>
<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="event" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${callsite:fileName=true}" source="NLogger"/>
<target name="console" xsi:type="Console"
        layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${stacktrace}|${message}" />
 </targets>

 <rules>
  <!-- add your logging rules here -->
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,event,viewer,console" />
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am adding this project dll to another project and its not working with no error.

I am creating the object to **logWrapper** class and calling the method to log the information, but it's not working at all.
Kindly let me know the mistake I am doing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**WHY** it did not run: Does your NEW project have that NLog.config file?

**IF** you need to load from a a single nlog.config for all the projects, you:

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration( "<your path>" + "\\NLog.config", true);
```

Comment: No, is that required? My intention is to keep the NLog project as a separate project and to have it's dll in 'n' number of projects.

Comment: Each project needs to have the configuration defined.

The DLL is shared across many projects, but each project can have a different way to log. So, each project should have its own nlog.config file.

Comment: if I include the config file in every project that refers to NLog, then my intention of having a single Nlog.config file to all the projects will be broken out. I need to maintain a single NLog.config file that too in NLog project and not in any other projects.

Comment: Your question was not clear. You asked why it did not run and that you want to deploy your logWrapper across multiple projects.
You did not indicate that you need to have a single nlog.config file across all projects. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Where should I add that code? In which project, either in NLog or the project which referring to NLog project.

Comment: The change is in your logWrapper class if you want to make it "permanent". I suggests you create a constructor that does it.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Lee, I am using your suggestion of loading the nlog.config using XmlLoggingConfiguration() method.